# Pass props from layout to children in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

How can I pass props from Gatsby layout to children (for example a Header component)?

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ children }) => {
    return <div>{children()}</div>;
};
```

The resources I found use the following format:

```
{ props.children({ ...props, foo: true }) }
{ this.props.children({...this.props, updateLayoutFunction }) }
```

But since there is no `props`, but only children, I can't get this to work. I tried this, but it also didn't work:

```
{ children({ foo: true }) }
```

In all cases, I get this error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'history.listen')`

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3412#event-1446894145
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2112

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But there are props, you're just not passing them to children.

In your layout file, instead of:

```
export default ({ children }) // ... etc
```

do

```
export default (props) {
  const myOwnProperties = { foo: true };

  return (
    {props.children({ ...props, ...myOwnProperties })}
  );
}
```

You see, the props are passed automatically until you add your own.

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: props.children is not a function"