# Styled components theme provider not passing object to props in gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am trying to pass theme object into the ThemeProvider like I always do in my standard React project. However, now when I am using gatsby I am unable to access theme inside children props. What can be the issue?
Here is my code:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <ThemeProvider theme={{ color: 'blue' }}>
        <>
          <Header />
          {children}
        </>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I try to console log props inside Header component I am getting empty object despite fact that I've correctly passed theme object into the ThemeProvider.

Comment: Does this shed any light on the problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48725557/10262432

Comment: I've changed children destructuring to props and then I've tried to pass it like that {props.children({...props})} but I gets error saying that props children is not a function.