# Creating an Observer component in React - Passing props to the children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to build an intersection observer component in a personal Gatsby project. The reason for it is the animation and trigger is the same in different areas of the site. What I have so far:

```js
// Observer.js

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useAnimation } from "framer-motion";

const Observer = ({ children }) => {
  const controls = useAnimation();

  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          controls.start({
            opacity: 1,
            transition: { duration: 0.75, delay: 0.75 },
          });
        }
      },
      {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: "0px",
        threshold: 0.1,
      }
    );
    if (ref.current) {
      observer.observe(ref.current);
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return <div ref={ref}>{children}</div>;
};

export default Observer;
```

What I am looking to do is access `controls` in the children of the `Observer.js` component.

```js
// ChildComponent.js

const ChildComponent= (props) => {

  return (
    <Observer>
      <div>
        <motion.div
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={props.controls}
        >
          <h2>This will animate on scroll</h2>
        </motion.div>
      </div>
    </Observer>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

I have seen answers such as - [Pass props from layout to children in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725557/pass-props-from-layout-to-children-in-gatsby) - but I get the error `props.children is not a function` when attempting this.

Is what I am looking to do possible, or is there a better way of achieving this?